# Formatting text to the title's style

Tags: formatting, titles, fontsize

Is there a way to format a sentence to the title's style?

I mean that if the input is a sentence, then the output is this sentence with all letters made uppercase while the original uppercase letters are a bit bigger than the original lowercase ones.

For example, the input is "Response to Editor's and Reviewers' Comments", then 
the output is

[image: The output text.]

I know the IEEEtran package can used to format the title to this format, but I would like to format another sentence other than a title.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\textsc` or `\scshape`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  {%<------open group to keep the formatting local
  \scshape Response to Editor's and Reviewers' Comments
  }%<------ close the group

  or

  \textsc{Response to Editor's and Reviewers' Comments}
\end{document}
```

[image]